# Why does Dell PowerEdge T330 force hardware RAID for 8 drive configuration?

Tags: software-raid, centos-7, hardware-raid, dell-poweredge

I'm considering the Dell PowerEdge T330 server tower to run CentOS Linux. The chassis configurations that can be ordered are either 4 3.5" hard drive slots or 8. We need to run a software RAID (that's our requirement) for this new system, not a hardware RAID. If you select the 8 drive slot option, it forces the option to have a hardware RAID. Dell sales said to use all 8 drive slots, it must be a hardware RAID. In Dell's notes in the ordering it says:

```
"If customer orders 
system with Software RAID, only 4 
drives can be populated and the rest 
of the drive slots will be blocked by 
four-slot drive blank and cannot be 
upgraded for additional storage"
```

Why not allow the customer to have access to all 8 drive slots? Why are they blocking the other drive slots? Is there a technical reason or is this an attempt to get the customer to buy a more expensive model?

The other part of this question is, can you have a hardware RAID in the system and simply not use it, and instead use a software RAID?

Comment: If I were to guess, it has to do with the limitations of the RAID controller being used, you should contact Dell and ask.